# Declarative authorization - allow editing others comments left in your article?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I'm following Ryan Bates' [declarative authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) railscast. I'm trying to add functionality for author of a particular article to be able to edit comments left in his article, regardless of if he is the owner or not. I tried doing it, but couldn't get it to work.

```
  role :author do
    has_permission_on :articles, :to => [:new, :create]
    has_permission_on :articles, :to => [:edit, :update, :show] do
      if_attribute :user => is { user }
    end
    **has_permission_on :comments, :to => [:edit, :update] do
      if_attribute :article_id => is { user }
    end**
  end
```

How do I modify the has_permission on comments line to allow user to edit comments if they are left in his article only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allow a user to edit the comments that are published in his/her articles, the rule should looks like:

```
role :author do
  [...]

  has_permission_on :comments, :to => [:edit, :update] do
    if_attribute :article_id => is_in { user.article_ids }
  end
end
```

Please, notice the change of **is** by **is_in**

Optionally, you may change the `user.article_ids` by `user.articles.collect{|a| a.id}.uniq`

Comment: Ah I didn't even think of using user.article_ids. Thanks that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first declaration...

```
has_permission_on :articles, :to => [:edit, :update, :show] do
  if_attribute :user => is { user }
end
```

... perfectly works, because if `:user` is equal to `user` (which is the current logged in user - current_user) you have permission to do the declared actions on `:articles`.

But if you look at the second one...

```
has_permission_on :comments, :to => [:edit, :update] do
  if_attribute :article_id => is { user }
end
```

you can see that the attribute `:article_id` is never going to be equal to the current logged in `user`.

Now I'm a Rails newbie myself and I just used some basic functionality of **declarative authorization**, so I don't know the exact answer to your problem. But I think you must find a way to access the articles of that `user`, something like `if_attribute :article_id => is { user.articles.id }`.

Maybe you can find an answer [here](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/0.1/) in the documentation

Comment: Yea I tried doing that without any help. I guess I'll need to pass in some additional parameters.